# Regarding PHP QUERY

Tags: php

```
<?php

$cat_id = $globalClass->getRow("prod_category","`category`='".$get_cat['id']."'");

for($m = 0; $m<count($cat_id); $m++)

{

$product = $globalClass->getRow1("product","`id`='".$cat_id[$m]['prod_id']."'");
if(!empty($product[0]['id']))
{
for($k=0; $k<count($product); $k++)

{



?>
```

How can i use order by name in ascending order in `$product = $globalClass->getRow1("product","`id`='".$cat_id[$m]['prod_id']."'");`

Comment: please provide more info as what getRow() this function do?

Comment: getRow as  declared in globalClass fetch all rows based on particular condition

Comment: Can you share that function..

Comment: {



   $this->connection();



   if(!empty($condition))



   {



    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `".$table."` where ".$condition) or die(mysql_error());



   }

Answer (score 0):

As per you info, i can suggest you as below:

```
$product = $globalClass->getRow1("product","id='".$cat_id[$m]['prod_id']."' order by name asc");
```

Comment: sir i have applied this but not working ,this comes in loop so how can we user order by name here

Comment: or we have to made separate function for that in globalClass

Comment: please reply me as soon as possible